# Switching JFrames without changing reference

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to keep this fairly clean and on a single reference to a `JFrame`, a cut and skinned version of the application is as follows:

```
public class Client extends SuperclassNotJFrame

     private JFrame frame;

     method a()
        frame = new Frame("first frame").setSize(400,400).setVisible(true)
     endmethod

     method b()
        frame = new Frame("second frame").setSize(800, 600).setVisible(true)
     endmethod

endclass
```

If I call method `a()` and then later call method `b()`, the frame created during method `a()` will stay, even though I've completely removed the reference the frame created there by over-writing it with the new frame.

I've even tried doing `frame = null` in `b()`, with the same result.

Comment: Take a look at [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) and [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) or [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) depending on your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `frame` invisible, you can use `frame.setVisible(false);`.

The object you created by calling the `Frame` constructor in method `a()` is not deleted immediately when the reference stops pointing to it. When you called `setVisible(true)` on the frame from `a()`, you created a window that will persist even after `a()` terminates.

Comment: But if the `frame` is overwritten, how is the reference to the old frame not destroyed?

Comment: Considering the edit to your question, how would i go about "deleting" the old frame properly. Shouldn't just removing the reference "delete" it and make it eligible for `gc()`

Comment: Thanks, the setVisible edit helps, so as-long as `a()->visible` the garbage collector will ignore it, even if `frame != a` right?

Comment: The *object* that `frame` points to in `a()` is garbage-collected eventually. You can't really delete a `JFrame`; if you want it to disappear on the screen (which I believe is your goal), simply call `setVisible(false);` on it.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain on whether or not references to the frame object persist; the Swing framework may be keeping it alive in some way, but the garbage collector only considers references to an object when deciding whether to delete it.